# What is "Service Provider Information" on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, setup-wizard

What is the "Service provider information" that this Android 12 Samsung Galaxy phone gathers upon setup?

Setup requires connection to a network, then says it needs to gather this info, then restart.

The only service provider I have identified on the phone is Wi-Fi.

Comment: I think its the information gathered to identify the device and to some extent the user for third party apps from a security standpoint for example as to whether you have the authority to access data based on some kind of arbitrary fact such as your location, region lock, et cetera.

Comment: Highly possibly a duplicate, but not yet answered: [What is Service Provider Setup on Samsung devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250780/44325)